# Make collapsible header correctly adaptive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to make an adaptive site with collapsible header. Header must collapse on document widths more than 992px, and must be just fixed on widths less than 992.

The problem is: when we resize window from big to small, ability to collapse doesn't disappear as it is expected. But when we resize from small to big window width it works.

I used simple jquery code:

```
$(function() {

    var width = $(document).width();

    $(window).on("orientationchange load resize", function() {
        width = $(document).width();
        if (width > 992) {
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                var header = $('header');

                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {

                    header.addClass('collapse');

                } else {

                    header.removeClass('collapse');
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Please look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/19fmc8wa/2/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, you almost had it. Let me know if I am off on the functionality at all, but I tried to keep similar to your orig code as possible.

```
  $(function(){

    function collapse(subj, removalBool){
        if (subj && !removalBool){
            $(subj).removeClass('collapse');
        }
        else {
            $(subj).addClass('collapse');
        }        
    }

    function changePos(){
        var pos = { 
            "fixed": 992
        };
    }


    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50 &&  $(document).width() > 992 ){
            collapse('header', true);

        }
        else {
            collapse('header');
        }
    });

});
```

Resize event does not need to be nested like you had it although I see what you were thinking. Instead, use your JavaScript to read the width of the document whenever the scroll event fires, as opposed to when the re-size event fires.

I then used CSS Media Queries to control the fixed position, dependent on screen  width:

```
header {
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
    transition: height .3s;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

}
main {
    background-color: #abc;
    height: 700px;
}
.collapse {
    background: yellow !important;
    height: 50px;
    transition: height .3s;
}

@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
      header {
      position: relative;
        background: blue;
    }   
}

@media all and (max-width: 992px) {
 header {
      position: fixed;
    }   
}
```

Hope this helps!

**UPDATED**
http://jsfiddle.net/19fmc8wa/6/

Comment: Header collapses on the small width. It must not. And everithing must work without page refresh

Comment: fixed, but you now have a new issue. When you shrink your height of your header element, it messes with the scrollTop() value and causes repeatitive recalculations based on this.